# (Auto) update SQL query/view after column renaming

Tags: c#, sql-server

So, before I'll adress the issue, you first have to understand the context of the problem.

**Context:**

> I'm making a module in .NET (C#) where a user can build his own
>   "views". A view is something that the user can view. It could be a
>   table view, chart view, spreadsheet view etc. A view is built based on
>   a SQL query. The user can build this query through a very user
>   friendly GUI, which is also known as the "query builder". This query
>   is being stored in the database, because the user wants to open his
>   view next time and immediately see the data in it.

**Problem:**

> It could be that we rename a certain column in the future. Which means
>   that the stored queries or views in the database also have to be
>   updated.

Whats the best way to do this?

**What I did/investigated:**

I know it's maybe better to create a table view instead of storing the query in a table. But that does not solve my problem.

Possible solutions:

**Solution 1:**
Create a database trigger. When a column is being renamed, you check all the stored views, substring the queries and replace the old column name with the new one. If I would use table views, I could delete the view and recreate it.

Disadvantage of this solution: performance issue's can occur when using a database trigger.

**Solution 2:**
A column has meta data. What I could do is store the column ids in a table along with the current column and table name.
When a column is being renamed, I loop through all columns in my saved queries, retrieve the metadata and check if the column name is still equal with the one in the metadata.

**Solution 3:**
Don't save the query in the database, create a serializable object that references to the database columns. The thing with this solution is that you solve it on code level, while it's a database issue.

Does anyone know a better solution for this? Is there a way to auto update views or queries when a column is being renamed?

Comment: Solution 4: don't rename columns?

Comment: Well, if that could be the case inside my company, I wouldn't ask this question in the first place.

Comment: You're moving an operational problem to the execution side. Imagine someone not renaming, but removing a column and adding one of the same data type. Does that count as a rename, or should the old column be removed from all stored queries? Anyway each solution is possible and has its own pros and cons, I guess you're the only one who can pick any.

Comment: I would consider giving everything (i.e. the columns they reference) an originalname and a currentname. Then run all of your queries using originalname. Then use `SELECT firstoriginalname as firstcurrentname, secondoriginalname as secondcurrentname FROM (yourexisting queryin here using originalnames)`. This allows you to have all of your joins, predicates etc using originalnames, but you change the names to the new names (at the last minute) for display. That way they can change `currentname` all they like - it won't impact the inner query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using NHibernate, the best solution would be number 3.
Make your domain entities serializable.

All you need to do when editing a column in the database, is change the mapping of your entity. Problem solved.